# Opencv detectMultiscale How to derive the optimal scaleFactor for images with TrainSize 33x5

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I trained my LBP-cascade with sample size 33x5. In the function detectMultiscale I use minSize 33x5. Now I observe, that the correct detection is closely dependent on the scaleFactor. For example with scaleFactor 1.09 I have a correct detection and with scaleFactor 1.091 the detection is completely different.

Comment: Provide a code sample please

Comment: @Andrew std::vector<Rect> rectangles;rect_cascade.detectMultiscale(frame_gray, rectangles, 1.10092,30,0, Size(33,5));